# Disable link detector doesn't work - objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

`self.webview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;`  doesn't work for my uiwebview for some reason. You can still are able to see the lin detection (see image below) 
[image]

How do I make it so the link detection doesn't come up when I press it? What code will work?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `UIWebView` a `delegate` and implement the -`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method to `return NO;` (except on the initial load).

That will prevent the user from viewing anything but that single page.

To provide an example requested in the comments... Start with `allowLoad=YES` and then:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    return allowLoad;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView {
    allowLoad = NO;
}
```

may be helped..happy coding..